# Entity Framework Core 3.0 query not pulling the required information

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to fetch data from two tables that has one to many relationship in Entity Framework Core 3. The models that represent the tables are shown below. One Person can have many PersonNotes. I need to query the PersonNotes table by passing the PersonId. I am currently getting an error saying Person does not contain the definition of Contains. How do I formulate this query.

```
class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
}

class PersonNote
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

class StackOverflow : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes  { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.PersonNotes)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);
    }
}
```

Query

```
public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
        {
            var PersonNotes1 = PersonNotes.Where(p => Person.Contains(p.Id)); 
            return PersonNotes1;
        }
```

Comment: `var PersonNotes1 = PersonNotes.Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);`

Answer (score 0):

To get `PersonNotes` by *one* `PersonID`:

```
IQueryable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotesSingleId(int ID) =>
    context.PersonNotes.Where(p => p.PersonId == ID);
```

To get `PersonNotes` by *multiple* `PersonID`s:

```
IQueryable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotesMultipleId(IEnumerable<int> IDs) =>
    context.PersonNotes.Where(p => IDs.Contains(p.PersonId));
```

The last query will generate `IN` T-SQL clause:

```
var notes = GetPersonNotesMultipleId(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```